# dynamic ViewPager2 height calculation for each item

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I am using the `ViewPager2` for showing the 3 adapter item.. and each item has a different layout. so the height of the `viwepager2` should be resized when changing the tab of the `viewpager2`.

Please suggest a solution for the `Viewpager2`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I achieved something like that with

```
    private fun updatePagerHeightForChild(view: View, pager: ViewPager2) {
        view.post {
            val wMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
            val hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            view.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)
                pager.layoutParams = (pager.layoutParams).also { lp -> lp.height = view.measuredHeight }
                pager.invalidate()
            }
    }
```

get the current page `view` using the below snippet:

```
    viewPager2.setPageTransformer { page, position ->
        updatePagerHeightForChild(page, viewPager2)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Blackbelt. it is working for me.. let me just edit few things in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this solution .. tweaking the apis for every small functionality .. android framework is kinda broken if you look into it

Comment: Try many solutions  and only this works for me. Thank you so much!